# resolveInstanceMethod on super returns NO for a valid selector

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've implemented +resolveInstanceMethod on a class that subclasses NSDictionary. I will dynamically add methods to my class for certain cases, but I want standard NSDictionary methods to 'just work'.

I thought this would be the case if I just call [super resolveInstanceMethod:sel]; at the end of my method but it doesn't work.

```
+ (BOOL) resolveInstanceMethod:(SEL)sel
{
    BOOL value = [super resolveInstanceMethod:sel]; // this is always NO!?
    return value;
}
```

Why is this? How do I get my class to behave 'normally' for existing methods on the superclass?

Comment: NSDictionary is a class cluster, so even its "standard methods" could be implemented by internal subclasses.

Comment: Thanks, any insight into how I make it work?

Comment: In what way is your class behaving abnormally?

Comment: Did you read the [“Methods to Override” subsection of “Subclassing Notes” in the *NSDictionary Class Reference*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000140-DontLinkElementID_1)?  Did you implement all of those methods?

Answer (score 0):

What leads you to expect that `-resolveInstanceMethod:` would return `YES` for already existing methods? The [release notes which introduced the new method](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/Cocoa/FoundationOlder.html) say that the default implementation simply returns NO:

> The NSObject class implements these methods with a default
>   implementation that returns NO today, though you should still invoke
>   it even if you're just directly subclassing NSObject.

In any case, it should never even be called for methods which are already present on the class. It's only called when you message an object with a selector which isn't already "resolved" to an implementation.